# Problems using SAPI with PHP through COM, on IIS

Tags: php, iis, com, sapi

I am attempting to get Text To Speech and Speech Recognition to work in PHP using Microsoft's SAPI through COM objects.

In the past, I already used this code to get TTS to work (Apache 2.1, PHP 5.5, on Windows 2003 Server)

```
// Instantiate the object
$VoiceObj = new COM("SAPI.SpVoice") or die("Unable to instantiate SAPI");

// Get the available voices
$VoicesToken=$VoiceObj->GetVoices();
$NumberofVoices=$VoicesToken->Count;
for($i=0;$i<$NumberofVoices;$i++)
{
 $VoiceToken=$VoicesToken->Item($i);  
 $VoiceName[$i]=$VoiceToken->GetDescription();
}

// Get and print the id of the specified voice
$SelectedVoiceToken=$VoicesToken->Item(0);
$SelectedVoiceTokenid=$SelectedVoiceToken->id;

// Set the Voice
$VoiceObj->Voice=$SelectedVoiceToken;
$VoiceName=$VoiceObj->Voice->GetDescription();

$VoiceFile = new COM("SAPI.SpFileStream"); 
$VoiceFile->Open('./test.wav', 3, false);


// Speak to file
$VoiceObj->AudioOutputStream = $VoiceFile;
$VoiceObj->Speak("What an unbelievable test", 0);
$VoiceFile->Close();
```

On my new setup (IIS 7.5, PHP 7.0, Windows Server 2008R2) the same code fails at

```
$VoiceObj->Speak("What an unbelievable test", 0);

Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: <b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown in \\web\tts.php:30 Stack trace: #0 \\web\tts.php(30): com->Speak('this is a marve...', 0) #1 {main}
```

With such little detail (where to retrieve more?) I can't figure out what the problem may be.

Writing permissions checked.
PHP 7.0 replaced with 5.5, still not working.
Same code tested with a Win32 app, and it works flawlessly.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two years later, I casually happen to find an answer to this problem.

*PHP COM Objects can't perform file operations on network paths, even with all the required permissions*

Once the development folders were moved on the same machine where IIS runs, a bunch of previously broken tests started working. They all had one thing in common: they were using COM interfaces to save files or something like that.